# Solution verification: using complex substitution when calculating Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

I have a question about Lebesgue integral with complex podintegral function (I am calculating the Fourier transform of the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2 } $ ). I tried following:

$$ \hat{f}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R} } e^{-x^2 } e^{-itx}dx = \int_{\mathbb{R} } e^{ -( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{i t}{\sqrt{2}}    )^2  - \frac{t^2}{2}}  dx  = e^{- \frac{t^2}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R} }  e^{ -( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{i t}{\sqrt{2}}    )^2}  dx $$

Now, is it allowed to use substitution  $ \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{i t}{\sqrt{2}}  = u$? Then,
$dt = \sqrt{2}du$, but what happens to the set of integration i.e. limits of integral? When I solved this way, I got the result $ \sqrt{2 \pi} e^{ -\frac{t^2}{2}} $, but I am not sure if I can use the  substition above in case of complex numbers.

I know there are some other methods to calculate this integral, but I am interested in correctness of this method. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You cannot make this substitution , but Complex Analysis can be used to show that if you do the computation when $it$ is replaced by a real number  then the formula you want is valid with $it, t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Could you please tell what I should use to prove that, I haven't used Complex Analysis in last often, so I forgot some things

Comment: In Probability Theory the integral you are evluating is called the characteristic function of Gaussian distribution. There are many ways in which you can evaluate it and there are dozens of places where you can find them . Many books on  Probability Theory have them and you can also locate them very easily on the net.